# How can I enable jumping to linked page if user clicks TextView?

Tags: android

**XML Layout**

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/behindMenuScrollContent"
    android:paddingTop="25dp" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemTitle"
        android:text="People" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/iconViewLink4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <jp.fureco.IconView 
            android:id="@+id/iconViewItem4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
            android:text="Visitor" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have **myWebView** just like this

```
WebView  myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

When a user clicks on `iconViewLink4`, I want it jump to the url "http://example.com/messsage"

How can I code that?

Answer (score 1):

Make it clickable and give it an OnClickListener (you can do this on any View)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/iconViewLink4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">

findViewById(R.id.iconViewLink4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

Comment: If you had iconViewLink4 something like 4 - iconViewLink20, how would you do that? would you do write your code for 17 times?

Comment: If you're going to have a list of links, use a ListView and have each item store the link it wants to open. Add an OnListItemClickListener, get the link from the clicked item, and do what you want.

Comment: for layout purpose I couldn't use ListView. So would you put your code for 17 times?

Comment: "for layout purpose I couldn't use ListView" - Are you planning to have 17 of these things on that screen? If so, think about using some kind of adapter-based View, even if it's not ListView.

Comment: Is it easy to use adapter based? My layout is just like this. https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-hoVDio62tgc/UOHBBU7K0LI/AAAAAAAAQWE/rEkvI2NgNl4/s720/simple_side_drawer02.png

Comment: By the way, your code returns this error `Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead`

Comment: I agree with Karakuri.Adapter based view would be better choice in such kind of situation.

Comment: Is it because of Memory leaks?

Comment: @Karakuri your code returns this error Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead

Comment: @MKK: IDE's like Eclipse have a number of useful tools to help you fix simple syntax errors. If you understand the approach, you can do the code yourself instead of copying it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just use android:onClick="methodName" in `<LinearLayout>` or add it programatically by using setOnClickListener like

```
LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.iconViewLink4);

linLay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // the method or code that will take control to your URL
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had iconViewLink4 something like 4 - iconViewLink20, how would you do that? would you do write your code for 17 times?